# Deploy ASP .NET MVC website with VS2012?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, ftp

So I am using Gearhost as my hosting provider. My MVC website is finished, but when I right click it to select the Publish option, I get a window asking me for a Profile, so I just create a new one.

But, what I would like to do is deploy to a local folder, and then upload the files using Filezilla, however I can't figure out how to do this.

So, my question is, how do I get the files that I need to upload via FTP?

Comment: from combobox in publish popup window choose `FileSystem` as a deployment method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you publish your MVC project, there are several methods of deployment available, for example FTP, FileSystem, WebDeploy. If you select the FTP publish method on the Connection tab you can fill out your credentials and upload straight to your ftp hosting space. If you deploy using FileSystem its relatively straight forward, you select a path to deploy your project to and then upload all the files in that folder to your hosting root. Try both options if your having difficulties.

More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337.aspx) for all methods of deployment.

Comment: thanks for the link, I went ahead and deployed the site using ms webmatrix and everything worked out all right